# Do you need to end a manual otel span even if an error happens?

Tags: open-telemetry

In other words, do I need to wrap my code in a try/finally?

```
tracer.startActiveSpan((span) => {
  try {
    // code here - maybe error is thrown
  } finally {
    span.end()
  }
));
```